# Oracle Regex: Accept all kind of values from Varchar2

Tags: sql, oracle

in Oracle's SQL, what does this expression mean?

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(firstname,'^[A-Za-z ,]+$');
```

And how can I change to permit any kind of Varchar2 values?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Luis

Comment: If you want to accept any kind of varchar2 values... when should it yield false ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that first name can have only lower and uppercase letters and a comma.

If you want to accept any character, remove the whole `WHERE` clause.